# Try add to cart without refresh page Django/Ajax (Internal Server Error)

Tags: ajax, django, forms

I have this error `cart/create/?product_id=1 500 (Internal Server Error)` I don't understand why:) I'm trying to use Ajax first. Try add product in the cart without refreshing page.

Add product from this link

```
<a href="#" data-id="{{ product.id }}" class="add_to_cart"><button>Add product</button></a>
```

my url

```
url(r'^cart/create/$', views.cart_create, name='cart_create'),
```

my view

```
def cart_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    product_id = request.GET.get('product_id')
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    cart.add(product=product)

    return JsonResponse('')
```

js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.add_to_cart').on('click', function(){
            product_id = $(this).attr('data-id')
            data = {
                product_id: product_id
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '{% url "cart:cart_create" %}',
                data: data,
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('success')
                }
            })
        })
    });
</script>
```

This base.html file, here I try output my count in the cart, and this works but only with refreshing

```
<header>
    {% with total_items=cart|length %}
        {% if cart|length > 0 %}
            Our cart:

            <a href="{% url 'cart:cart_show' %}" id="cart_count">
                {{ total_items }} products {{ cart.get_total_price }} &#8381;
            </a>
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% url 'cart:cart_show' %}">Cart is empty</a>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}

    <h1><a href="{% url 'shop:product_list' %}">Main</a ></h1>
</header>
```

Why I'm doing wrong guys?

```
terminal
Internal Server Error: /cart/create/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kory/project/django-shop/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/kory/project/django-shop/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/kory/project/django-shop/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/kory/project/django-shop/cart/views.py", line 21, in cart_create
    return JsonResponse('')
  File "/home/kory/project/django-shop/.env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/http/response.py", line 552, in __init__
    'In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the '
TypeError: In order to allow non-dict objects to be serialized set the safe parameter to False.
```

```
console.log
jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost:8000/cart/create/?product_id=1 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Comment: show us the full error stack trace

Comment: @dirkgroten, updated

Comment: `JsonResponse` takes a dict as its `data` argument, not a string. It's good practice, even in case of success, to send something back, e.g. `JsonResponse({'status': 'OK'})` but `JsonResponse({})` would also work.

Comment: @dirkgroten, oh thank you: it's helped me)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects) for a description of `JsonResponse`.

You need to pass a `dict` to `JsonResponse`, not just an empty string. Or, if you set `safe=False`, you can pass a json serialisable object. But even then I don't think an empty string is valid JSON.